# VC++ 2017 Could not find VC++ tools version "14.16.27023"

Tags: visual-c++

I've installed Visual 2017 C++ build tools. I am attempting to run `vsdevcmd` to prepare the environment. But, I am getting an error stating VC++ tools are not installed when they infact are.

Below is the error I am getting:

```
[DEBUG:vcvars.bat] Could not find VC++ tools version "14.16.27023" under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\".
[DEBUG:ext\vcvars.bat] init:COMPLETE
[DEBUG:core\vsdevcmd_end] initializing with arguments ''
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] In an uninitialized command prompt, please 'set VSCMD_DEBUG=[value]' and then re-run
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] vsdevcmd.bat [args] for additional details.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Where [value] is:
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    1 : basic debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    2 : detailed debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    3 : trace level logging. Redirection of output to a file when using this level is recommended.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Example: set VSCMD_DEBUG=3
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]          vsdevcmd.bat > vsdevcmd.trace.txt 2>&1
[DEBUG:VsDevCmd] Writing post-execution environment to C:\Users\KRAFTW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vsdevcmd15_env.log
[DEBUG:VsDevCmd.bat] --------------------- VS Developer Command Prompt Environment [post-init] ---------------------
```

Here's the level 3 error reporting of that specific error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC>if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\" (
set "VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\"
 set "VCToolsVersion=14.16.27023"
)  else (
set VCToolsInstallDir=
 if "3" GEQ "2"
 goto :end
)
[DEBUG:vcvars.bat] Could not find VC++ tools version "14.16.27023" under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\".
```

That directory exists because I copied and pasted the path and was able to change into that directory. Using explorer I can also see that exact version does exist, and within it all the expected tools (as can be seen in the image below)

[image]

Any ideas what the problem could be?

**Edit**

As Hans pointed out in the comment there is wild character at the beginning of the filename `14.16.27023`.

[image]

According to the output it's loading the path from here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC>set "__VCVARS_DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\Microsoft.VCToolsVersion.default.txt"`

I've inspected this file and it contains the following (no odd character):

[image]

Also viewed with a hex editor and there's nothing there:

[image]

I inspected the `vcdevcmd.bat` file and it's failing at this:

```
@REM *****************************************************************
@REM This section executes all .bat files found in vsdevcmd\ext.
@REM Any "leaf node" script should be placed in this directory.
@REM A few notes:
@REM * For determinism sake, the scripts are called in alphabetical
@REM   order.
@REM * This section does NOT recursively look in sub-directories
@REM   under vsdevcmd\ext. Sub-directories may be used for
@REM   "implementation detail" scripts called by .bat files in the
@REM   vsdevcmd\ext folder.
@REM *****************************************************************

@REM Iterate through ext scripts
if NOT EXIST "%VS150COMNTOOLS%vsdevcmd\ext\" (
    @echo [ERROR:%~nx0] Cannot find 'ext' folder "%VS150COMNTOOLS%vsdevcmd\ext\"
    set /A __vscmd_vsdevcmd_errcount=__vscmd_vsdevcmd_errcount+1
    goto :ext_end
)

for /F %%a in ( 'dir "%VS150COMNTOOLS%vsdevcmd\ext\*.bat" /b /a-d-h /on' ) do (
    call :call_script_helper ext\%%a
)

:ext_end
set __vscmd_dir_cmd_opt=
exit /B 0
```

with the error:

```
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[ERROR:ext\] init:FAILED code:1
```

Now I'm not even sure if these 2 errors are related but both appear in the logs. I have attempted complete removed of VS and all of it's products. I've reinstalled with a fresh installer, to no avail.

Thing is, I had this working initially.

**Edit 2**

Ok, here is the problem with being unable to load VC++ tools (from `vcvars.bat`):

```
:export_env_vctoolsinstalldir
if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\%__VCVARS_TOOLS_VERSION%\" (
    set "VCToolsInstallDir=%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\%__VCVARS_TOOLS_VERSION%\"
    set "VCToolsVersion=%__VCVARS_TOOLS_VERSION%"
) else (
    set VCToolsInstallDir=
    if "%VSCMD_DEBUG%" GEQ "2" @echo [DEBUG:%~nx0] Could not find VC++ tools version "%__VCVARS_TOOLS_VERSION%" under "%VCINSTALLDIR%Tools\MSVC\".
    goto :end
)
```

I can't find any env. variables set for `__VCVARS_TOOLS_VERSION` or `VCVARS_TOOLS_VERSION`. If I could set that, maybe I can get it to work.

Found this at the head of the same file:

```
if "%__VCVARS_VERSION%" NEQ "" (
    set __VCVARS_TOOLS_VERSION=%__VCVARS_VERSION%
    goto :export_env_vctoolsinstalldir
)
```

I attempted to set that variable and rerun `vcdevcmd` but it still failed:

```
set __VCVARS_VERSION=14.16.27023
```

Also tried:

```
vsdevcmd -arch=amd64 -host_arch=amd64 -vcvars_ver=14.16.27023
```

That produces the error:

```
[DEBUG:vcvars.bat] Checking architecture { host , tgt } : { x86 , x86 }
[DEBUG:vcvars.bat] Could not add directory to PATH: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages"
[DEBUG:vcvars.bat] Could not find VC++ tools version "14.16.27023" under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\".
[DEBUG:ext\vcvars.bat] init:COMPLETE
```

Comment: There is a wonky extra character in the version number string that is hard to see in the SO post.  "14.16.27023", it is U+000C.  That explains the mismatch.  In a normal VS2017 install the tools version number gets read from a text file named Microsoft.VCToolsVersion.default.txt (vc/auxiliary/build subdirectory), I don't know how is done with this package.  Corruption of this file would explain it, if you find it back then just re-type the content.

Comment: Turns out it isn't visible in the comment either, it is the first character in the string  "14.16.27023".

Comment: Ah yes I did notice that. I've tried to reinstall numerous times to no avail.

Comment: Updated with a little more info.